# Как протестировать Optional.orElseThrow()

Tags: java, spring, юнит-тесты, тестирование, mockito

У меня есть метод, использующий репозиторий использующий `Optional.orElseThrow` внутри сервиса.

Как правильно реализовать конструкцию `when(restLogRepository.findById(anyLong()).thenReturn(log);`
? Мой способ, очевидно, неправильный

**Сервис**

```
public RestLogDto readById(Long id) {
    return DtoConverter.convert(
        restLogRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new NoSuchElementException("Element not found")),
        modelMapper);
    }
```

**Тестовый метод (неправильный)**

```
@Test
public void readById() {
    RestLog log = new RestLog();
    log.setLogId(LOG_ID);

    when(restLogRepository.findById(anyLong()).orElseThrow(any(Supplier.class))).thenReturn(log);
    RestLogDto result = DtoConverter.convert(log, mapper);

    assertEquals(result, logReader.readById(LOG_ID));
}
```

Comment: Вам надо возвращать Optional<RestLog> `when(restLogRepository.findById(anyLong()).thenReturn(Optional.of(log))` - вроде как-то так. Если по id не найдено - `Optional.empty()`

Comment: Надо ещё протестировать случай, когда будет выброшено исключение NoSuchElementException. `when(restLogRepository.findById(anyLong()).thenThrow(new NoSuchElementException())`

Comment: @АлександрПоташев про Optional, какую-то муть написали, это точно лишнее

Comment: @Leonis еще одна муть - тест не должен сам кидать NoSuchElementException, его должен кинуть DtoConverter.convert(), а вот проверять эту ошибку должен

Comment: `restLogRepository.findById(...)` как вижу должен возвращать Optional, 
а метод .orElseThrow() как раз и вызывается у Optional.

Comment: @keekkenen, сорри, да, заработался. Надо проверить 2 варианта - когда значение при `findById(id)` было найдено и когда не было найдено. Ниже дан верный ответ с примером

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DtoConverter entity = spy(new DtoConverter());
entity.setId(5);
doReturn(Optional.of(entity)).when(restLogRepository).findById(any());

assertEquals(5, logReader.readById(5));
```

Comment: Это если я правильно понял ваш код ))

Comment: Все корректно. Если вам надо протестировать нормальное получение объекта по id, то так, если конструкцию orElseThrow, то мокаете в качестве возврата из метода findById Optional.empty()

Comment: Да, окей, я перепроверил - это действительно рабочий вариант, спасибо.